# GT521F52 Fingerprint sensor library

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, fingerprint

I have a GT-521F32/52 FP sensor and Rpi 3 B. I am looking at this library but it doesn't seem to work. 
http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/article/test-of-the-gt-521f52-fingerprint-reader

I also checked this http://www.yoctopuce.com/EN/article/test-of-the-gt-521f52-fingerprint-reader but doesn't fit with what I want.

Do you know other fingerprint python library that works with GT-521F32/52?

Comment: Unfortunately, requests for off-site resources are off-topic for SO. However, looking at this library it looks extremely simple. It shouldn't be too hard to find out *why* it's not working. Bet bet: Have a go, and when you get stuck, come back here with a *specific* question, about the bit you're stuck with. Unless it's a hardware-y Pi-specific problem, of course, there are other SE sites for that.

Comment: Are you also using the Yocto USB-serial PCB? If not, then that is most likely your problem, as the library depends on it.